# MySQLi mysqli fech array assoc replacement NO working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, procedure, statements

here is what I want but cannot make it work with the new MySQLi just because my host does not have all new php etc...

But there must be some kind of solution or thats all MYSQLI can do ?

Please dont talk about PDO because even the ugly name sounds like PEDO and I am only interested in MySQLI and a solution for this simple thing. Please dont change the structure of my script. The question is only is if there is something to make it work with MySQL or if I maybe switch back to MySQL procedure instead of statements

```
    <?php
    $sql = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','db'); 
    $who  = $_GET['user'];
    $query = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user=?");
    $query->bind_param("s",$who);
    $result = $query->execute();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) // << HERE IS THE PROBLEM //

// I GET ERROR Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in ... //
```

"" but there must be some way to make it work like we do with while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))  //

```
    {
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    CUSTOM HTML FOR A NICE DESIGN I WANT TO KEEP THE SAME DESIGN LAYOUT ETC...

        HELLO <?php echo "$row[USERNAME]"; ?> 
        YOUR INFO IS <?php echo "$row[JUST_SOME_INFO]"; ?> 


    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `dont talk about PDO because even the ugly name sounds like PEDO` you win the interwebz

Comment: hahaha really the name does not sounds good

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

You don't have to use `fetch_array()` but use `fetch()`

also you will have to bind result using `bind_result` before `fetch`

```
$query->execute();

$query->bind_result($col1);

while($row = $query->fetch()){
     printf("%s \n", $col1);
}
```

You can use `$col1` directly also, no need to use it with `printf()`

My working example according to my db is given below if you want more assistance,

```
$sql = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','dbname');

$who  = 'php';

$query = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM job WHERE skill=?");

$query->bind_param("s",$who);


$query->execute();

$query->bind_result($col1);

while($row = $query->fetch()){
     printf("%s \n", $col1);
}
```

Comment: almost working or diferent result was Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in

Comment: use $query->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3,...) likewise so if your table has 3 rows use 3 varibles in bind_result.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this string:

```
$result = $query->get_result();
```

you don't need this.

Comment: Hi. Edited it and now I get the follow error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Comment: Check your `$result` first. I think, you have an empty value (NULL) as a result of your query. May be you have no record with this `$who` in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$who = $_GET['user'];
$query = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user=?");
$query->bind_param("s", $who);
$result = $query->execute() or die($query->error);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $username = $row[USERNAME];
    $info = $row[JUST_SOME_INFO];
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    CUSTOM HTML FOR A NICE DESIGN I WANT TO KEEP THE SAME DESIGN LAYOUT ETC...

    HELLO <?php echo $username; ?> 
    YOUR INFO IS <?php echo $info; ?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edited it your way and Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in

Comment: I think you should initialize another variable which holds the retrieve data from the database. 

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $username = $row['USERNAME'];
    $info = $row['JUST_SOME_INFO'];
}

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you start copying and pasting php together without knowing what it means.

the solution here is:

create a class for `$sql` or declare $sql a global imediately after calling the variable.

try

`global $sql;`

but if you actually want to fix the problem(by making your `$sql` variable an object)

try

```
$sql = array();
$sql['host'] = 'host';
$sql['user'] = 'user';
$sql['pass'] = 'password';
$sql['db'] = 'database';
global $sql;
$db = new mysqli($sql);
```

Now when you wanna do something with the db connection.

```
$db->action();
```

this is just the basics and probably won't work. you probably should instead read more on php/mysqli before attempting to write your own classes.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with procedural code at all. i use it for most things.